# Accessing QList<structure_type> from qml using qqmlproperty map

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to access the value of qqml property map which gives me QList<user_defined_structure>, but I am unable to access the values, it says undefined.

C++

```
struct user_defined_structure
{
int a;
int b;
};

Q_PROPERTY(QQmlProperty* myMap READ getMyMap CONSTANT)
```

How do I access each structure values in Qml??
myMap.key gives me QList<user_defined_structure>

Comment: Not. QqmlPropertyMap requires the type in the list to derive from QObject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit your custom struct from `QObject`:

```cpp
class user_defined_structure : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int a  MEMBER a  NOTIFY propertyChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int b  MEMBER b  NOTIFY propertyChanged)

  public:
    user_defined_structure(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

  signals:
    void propertyChanged ();  // NOTIFY signal must be specified to allow QML property bindings
};
```

To use it in another class:

```cpp
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(user_defined_structure* myStruct  READ getMyStruct  NOTIFY propertyChanged)

  public:
    MyClass(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    user_defined_structure* getMyStruct() const;
};
```

To use it in Qml:

```cpp
int main()
{
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("myClass"), &myClass);
}
```

```
ListView {
    model: myClass.myStruct
}
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not my use case.

QQmlProperty map will return me QList<structure_type> how do I access this in QML
I have also Decalared Q_DECLARE_METATYPE<QList<user_defined_struct>>

Comment: Have you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html ?